# Face recognition error due to size of the image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to write an script in Python and I am having some problems with that:
Firstly, I have a function that gets from a VideoStream a frame and resize it:

```
originalFrame = vs.read()
frame = imutils.resize(originalFrame, width=500)
```

After that I get the RGB image and detect the boxes of each face that the video stream recognize, coordinates:

```
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model=args["detectionMethod"])
```

Each box is compounded by (top, right, bottom, left) coordinates.
Now I want to process that tuple with another tool that provides me the age and gender of the person in front of the camera, and I am having some trouble because I want each box to be converted as a Numpy ndarray with the same coordinates as detections has in this following code:

```
    face = frame[box[2]:box[0], box[3]:box[1]]

# construct a blob from *just* the face ROI
faceBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, (227, 227), (78.4263377603, 87.7689143744, 114.895847746),swapRB=False)
```

But the log says:

```
 faceBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, (227, 227), (78.4263377603, 87.7689143744, 114.895847746),swapRB=False)
"cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/pi/.../imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3718: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

What can I do?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your array is empty as said in the error. [mre]

Comment: the bounds for the slice are the wrong way around. that's why the slice is empty. and that's what causes the follow-on issues. -- debug your code. look at variables.